Using PyautoCAD, how do I import DWG files
I'm trying to import a DWG file of a 3d model I have onto pyautoCAD. However, I can't find any detailed documentation about importing it. Furthermore, I also need to scale the size and find the placement with coordinates.
I tried using acad.doc.open("C:file/path") but it shows me an error.

Which error? My recommendation, if you find bad documentation, do not uses such tool. It will give only problems.

it should be something like
newDoc = acad.Documents.Open("path")
and you may need to make it the active document
acad.ActiveDocument = newDoc
